# power bi - replaced date value is not right

Tags: replace, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

everyone. I have a data that contains week numbers and year number in this format:

1-2022

I want to replace the value with proper date like 1/5/2022 (month, day, year format). However, not all the values are replaced in the right way. Some of the rows have 11/5/2022 instead of 1/5/2022. I checked the syntax and replace value dialog as well. Interestingly it only happens in two cases:

1-2022 >>> 1/5/2022 - instead I get: 11/5/2022

2-2022 >>> 1/12/2022 - instead I get: 11/12/2022

The rest of the values in January or any other month does not have any problem like this.

Below is an example formula:

```
    = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Week 53 - Replace","1-2022","1/5/2022",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Week"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're seeing isn't "1-2022" that gets changed to "1/5/2022" but rather "11-2022" that gets changed to "11/5/2022" since you're only replacing the last part of "1(1-2022)".

What I'd do is create a date table and add a week-year to it. Then just create a relation between the two and add the first Date from DimDate.

```
DimDate =
ADDCOLUMNS(
CALENDAR(
    "01-01-2022",
    "31-12-2022"
),
"Week-Year", WEEKNUM( [Date], 21 ) & "-" & YEAR( [Date] )
)
```

You'd need to replace the return type of WEEKNUM to match the data; 21 is ISO 8601 week.